# TinyMCE editor doesn't initialize

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm building a simple CMS in Ruby on Rails and I decided to use WYSIWYG editor with syntax highlighting, so I chose TinyMCE. Though, while trying to use it, I was stuck with a couple of issues:

**The first** issue is that I had an error while trying to run my test blog with my CMS. First I included

```
s.add_dependency "tinymce-rails"
```

into `mycms.gemspec` and ran

```
$ bundle install
```

then I added

```
//= require tinymce
```

line into `application.js` in my CMS. But when I included my CMS plugin (which comes as a separate gem) into my test blog, I couldn't reach my admin panel because of an error -- Rails couldn't find `tinymce` and I need to include `gem tinymce-rails` also in my test app's Gemfile to get it work. (The same issue I've got with `gem bootstrap-sass` -- only after including it into app's Gemfile it worked, though it was present in `mycms.gemspec`

**The second** issue is that the editor itself doesn't initialize and is not displayed in my page. So, here comes the form itself:

```
<%= form_for (@entry, as: :entry, url: entries_path) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %> <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <% @entry.class.content_attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_type| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :title %><br />
      <%= f.text_area attr_name, as: attr_type, class:"tinymce", rows:"40", cols:"120" %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= tinymce %>
```

And the textarea is just missing. I tried all the variants -- included

```
//= require tinymce
```

or

```
//= require tinymce-jquery
```

both into test app's `application.js` or CMS's `application.js`, as well as adding

```
<%= tinymce_assets %>
```

directly at the beginning of the form, but neither of these variants didn't work. What have I missed or done wrong?

The complete code of my CMS is available on [Github](https://github.com/AlexNikolaev94/multiflora_cms/tree/development)

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't added this javascript code, try adding this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  return tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    height: 100,
    width: 550,
    menubar: false,
    plugins: ['image', 'charmap', 'uploadimage'],
    toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link uploadimage | charmap ',
    theme: 'modern',
    relative_urls: false,
    remove_script_host: false,
    document_base_url: (!window.location.origin ? window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host : window.location.origin) + '/',
    setup: function(ed) {
      ed.on('init', function() {
        ed.getDoc().body.style.fontSize = '14px';
      });
      ed.on('change', function() {
        ed.save();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks! should I add it into my `.erb` form or directly into `application.js`?

Comment: It is better to put in application.js file.